# Ringbuffer with sprintf

Tags: c, string, buffer, strtok

I'm trying to create a ringbuffer and fill it with an array of split string elements. **Buffer Code** is taken from [here](https://jlmedina123.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/circular-buffer-queue/) and works well enough.

Here is my main and the buffer implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 struct buffer {
    int size;
    int start;
    //int end;  // position of last element
    /* Tracking start and end of buffer would waste
     * one position. A full buffer would always have
     * to leave last position empty or otherwise
     * it would look empty. Instead this buffer uses
     * count to track if buffer is empty or full
     */
    int count; // number of elements in buffer
    /* Two ways to make buffer element type opaque
     * First is by using typedef for the element
     * pointer. Second is by using void pointer.
     */
    /* different types of buffer:
    int *element;   // array of integers
    char *element;  // array of characters
    void *element;  // array of void type (could cast to int, char, etc)
    char **element; //array of char pointers (array of strings)
    void **element; // array of void pointers
    Choosing array of void pointers since it's the most flexible */
    char **element;
};

typedef struct buffer buffer_t;

void init(buffer_t *buffer, int size) {
    buffer->size = size;
    buffer->start = 0;
    buffer->count = 0;
    buffer->element = malloc(sizeof(buffer->element)*size);
    /* allocated array of void pointers. Same as below */
    //buffer->element = malloc(sizeof(void *) * size);

}

int full(buffer_t *buffer) {
    if (buffer->count == buffer->size) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int empty(buffer_t *buffer) {
    if (buffer->count == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void push(buffer_t *buffer, void *data) {
    int index;
    if (full(buffer)) {
        printf("Buffer overflow\n");
    } else {
        index = buffer->start + buffer->count++;
        if (index >= buffer->size) {
            index = 0;
        }
        buffer->element[index] = data;
    }
}


void * popqueue(buffer_t *buffer) {
    void * element;
    if (empty(buffer)) {
        printf("Buffer underflow\n");
        return "0";
    } else {
        /* FIFO implementation */
        element = buffer->element[buffer->start];
        buffer->start++;
        buffer->count--;
        if (buffer->start == buffer->size) {
            buffer->start = 0;
        }

        return element;
    }
}


int main() {
    char input[] = "[MVOLT][S1][M1]40.05[S1][M2]39.95";
    char *string_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    buffer_t buffer;
    init(&buffer, 5);

    char delimiter[] = "[";
    char *ptr;

    int i;
    ptr = strtok(input, delimiter);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sprintf(string_buffer,"[%s", ptr);
        printf("push: %s", string_buffer);
        // works but with missing character
        push(&buffer, ptr);
        // outputs the last element to the queue?
        push(&buffer, string_buffer);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("pop from queue: %s\n", popqueue(&buffer));
    }


}
```

When I pass the ptr element to the push function everything works correctly. However if I use sprintf to add the missing character I only get the last element. What is sprintf doing that is triggering this behavior?

Output from putting the ptr input directly:

```
push: [MVOLT]
push: [S1]
push: [M1]40.05
push: [S1]
push: [M2]39.95

pop from queue: MVOLT]
pop from queue: S1]
pop from queue: M1]40.05
pop from queue: S1]
pop from queue: M2]39.95
```

Output using sprintf:

```
push: [MVOLT]
push: [S1]
push: [M1]40.05
push: [S1]
push: [M2]39.95

pop from queue: [M2]39.95
pop from queue: [M2]39.95
pop from queue: [M2]39.95
pop from queue: [M2]39.95
pop from queue: [M2]39.95
```

Comment: My ***guess*** (since you don't show a [mcve] including the `push` function) is that you only store a *pointer*. Storing a pointer so a single buffer will store the same pointer to the same single buffer.

Comment: How about show push and pop?

Comment: I linked the code, but I will include that as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that makes sense, I tried simply moving the pointer to the left by storing ptr-1 to the buffer but that only seems to work for the first push.

Comment: `buffer->element[index] = data;` only copies the pointer, not the _string_ it points to.

Comment: Yup, understood. ptr-1 also doesnt work because of the way strtok works.

Answer (score 1):

As I guessed, you have an array of pointers and only store pointers.

When you do

```
push(&buffer, string_buffer);
```

you pass a pointer to the first element of the `string_buffer` array. This pointer will always be the same.

One possible solution is to use the non-standard (but commonly available) `strdup` function to dynamically create a new string:

```
push(&buffer, strdup(string_buffer));
```

Note that this requires you to `free` the pointer when you're done with it, or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Good idea, but that seems overkill. How would I free the pointer that to the new string? From the buffer?

Comment: @Julian Store the pointer returned by `popqueue` in a variable, and pass it to `free` it after printing it.

Comment: @Julian Overkill - No.  Code for proper functionality, then address "overkill".